# Morse code algorithm

Tags: algorithm, morse-code

Morse code is the cheapest and most popular way of message communitcation. In Morse code, each letter of the alphabet is represented by a sequence of dots and dashes. Traditionally, dots were transmitted by a short note and dashes by a longer note, with pauses between different letters.
Morse code representation of each letter of the english alphabet are as follows

```
a .-
b -...
c -.-.
d -..
e .
f ..-.
g --.
h ....
i ..
j .---
k -.-
l .-..
m --
n -.
o ---
p .--.
q --.-
r .-.
s ...
t -
u ..-
v ...-
w .--
x -..-
y -.--
z --..
```

For example, let the message is `-..-----.` and it is made up of three letters, it might mean njg, dog, xmg or xon.

I want to know the algorithm. What I know that we can make HashMap having keys as dot or line and having values as alphabets. But now I am not able to think how to check for each different word formed. Maybe recursion or dynamic programming can do this but please give me the algorithm so that I can start coding.

Comment: *Please give me the algorithm so that I can start coding.* Coding is only half of the job, coming up with an algorithm is the interesting part. We won't do that for you, but we can help you if you try something.

Comment: `Morse code is the cheapest and most popular way of message communication`. In the 21st century? Note that "with pauses between different letters"; you don't need to guess which words a combination of dots and dashes might be if you actually have a break between letters.

Comment: When sent by hand Morse uses both inter-letter and an inter-word pauses, just as we do in writing.  A proper alphabet for Morse has 3 symbols, a dot a dash and a representation for a dot-length space (which can be used multiple times for inter-letter and inter-word spaces).

Answer (score 5):

Morse code uses pauses between letters and longer pauses between words. That's how you separate them; you can't tell from just the dots and dashes.

Comment: For example "-...-.-." can be "-.. .- .-." (dar) or "-... -.-." (bc)

Comment: My question is if you given morse code for example -..-----. then 4 words can be formed of 3 letters njg, dog, xmg or xon then how to find all these words. Its easy to find one word but how to find all the words?

Comment: @user2963445: That sounds like the kind of useless-but-educational problem only given as homework. I'm not giving you the answer to your homework. I will give you the following hint, though: figure out what letters could be the first letter, then for each possible first letter, figure out how to break the rest of the string into letters.